# My kivy program keeps printing a blank white background when its supposed to be a picture

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class BackGround(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    pass

class Buttons(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Buttons, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=1
        self.add_widget(Button(text='clear wanted level',size=(180,100),size_hint=(None,None)))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return BackGround()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

this is my python code

```
<Background>:
    Buttons:
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: r'C:\Users\khanb\Desktop\images
```

this is my .kv code and instead of posting the picture it posts a blank white background

Comment: I keep getting this error [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <C:\Users\khanb\Desktop\images>

Answer (score 0):

a white background is kivy's default behaviour in case it doesn't recognize any images. also, i think this is a mistake since the source doesn't seem to have a ' at the end, but you forgot to add an actual file, you just gave them a directory, and not even the files inside of it. so i'm pretty sure you just gave them a bad directory, try copying the absulote path of the file and pasting it into the source.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the image inside the project file in order for the image to display. For example, if the image is inside the project file, then you can just reference it like this.

```
<Background>:
    Buttons:
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: "myimage.png"
```